# CRM Connection String when using On-Premise IFD and MFA

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, adfs, multi-factor-authentication

Have recently converted an application that connects to Dynamics CRM to use the new CRM Tooling connection method. It used an old method of connecting to CRM and I needed to update the connection method to support modern CRM Online.

No problem with this part,

```
IOrganizationService _crmService;
string connectionString = "....my crm connection string....";
CrmServiceClient service = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);
_crmService = (IOrganizationService)service.OrganizationWebProxyClient != null ? (IOrganizationService)service.OrganizationWebProxyClient : (IOrganizationService)service.OrganizationServiceProxy;
```

This all works and can connect to IFD On-Premise deployments and CRM Online.

IFD is connecting with a string in this format:

```
AuthType=IFD;Url=https://crmorg.crmprovider.com/CRMORG;Username=myuser@domain.com;Password=MyPass;Domain=NETBIOSDOMAIN;
```

It can also support MFA with CRM Online by registering an app in Azure and configuring a connection string in this format:

```
AuthType=OAuth;Url=https://yourcrm.crm.dynamics.com;AppId=APPID;RedirectUri=http://localhost;
```

What I am stuck on, is the format of the string on an IFD (On-Premise) deployment using On-Premise Microsoft MFA.

When I use the OAuth method with Azure AD, the application pops up a Microsoft Sign in Assistant that handles the user/pass and two factor request.

How do I construct a CRM Connection string that will do the same with an On-Premise CRM365 Deployment using the latest ADFS and MFA components from Microsoft?  I know that the On-Premise installation challenges your user/pass (via ADFS) like the Microsoft Sign in Assistant, but how do I invoke that method of connecting when not working with CRM Online?

Comment: no one got any ideas on this?  ive asked in several forums and nothing.. i can;t be the only person on planet earth trying to connect to an on-prem MFA implementation?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/xrm-tooling/use-connection-strings-xrm-tooling-connect?view=op-9-1#oauth-using-named-account-in-dynamics-365-customer-engagement-on-premises-with-ux-to-prompt-for-authentication):

OAuth using named account in Dynamics 365 Customer Engagement (on-premises) with UX to prompt for authentication

Create a new connection using a UserID or Password via oAuth.

OAuth is the preferred auth type for connecting to Dynamics 365 Customer Engagement (on-premises) when using an interactive flow. **This auth type fully supports the features of Azure Active Directory Conditional Access and Multi-Factor authentication.**

```
AuthType=OAuth;  
Username=jsmith;  
Password=passcode;  
Url=https://contoso:8080/Test;  
AppId=51f81489-12ee-4a9e-aaae-a2591f45987d;      
RedirectUri=app://58145B91-0C36-4500-8554-080854F2AC97;     
TokenCacheStorePath=c:\MyTokenCache;  
LoginPrompt=Auto
```